# This happens when Genymotion Tried to start up a device

Tags: virtualbox

I tried to start up a device on Genymotion and this error came up

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fSSI.png)

Unable to start the virtual device.

VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device.

Your CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies.

For more information, check the log files. Please refer to: [www.genymotion.com/faq/logs](http://www.genymotion.com/faq/logs)

This is what came up when I try starting a device. My computer is Hewlett-Packard HP EliteDesk 800 G1 TWR which has an Intel Core i5-4570 and Intel Hd Graphics 4600.
I posted this on stack overflow but someone told me to post it here.
I have found what the problem is: in my Bios Virtualization Technology is off but I can't turn it on

Comment: Have you looked up to see if your CPU supports virtualization? Intel has good documentation on their CPU specs, and it's usually the top result when you search the CPU model number. Also, have you followed that link and the instructions to collect your logs and checked to see what other info the provide?

Comment: I checked my cpu and it say 
intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) ‡ Yes
Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d) ‡ Yes

Comment: *in my Bios Virtualization Technology is off but I can't turn it on* That explains the message because it must be ON, obviously. What exactly happens when you try to enable it?